# Xamarin.Android: Change ProgessDialog Background Color Programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android, background-color, progressdialog

I am using a **ProgressDialog** while loading the next Activity in my Xamarin.Android App.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

I can set the Circle-Color programmatically:

```
Drawable circle = new ProgressBar(this).IndeterminateDrawable.Mutate();
circle.SetColorFilter(Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
progressDialog.SetIndeterminateDrawable(circle);
```

and I can set the Text-Color programmatically:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("This is my message");
ss.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Red), 0, ss.Length(), 0);
progressDialog.SetMessage(ss);
```

But I can't find a way to set the Background-Color programmatically.
Maybe you can help me with this problem. I do not want to use a Style.Theme.

**EDIT**:

It seems that creating a full custom view, which is used in a AlertDialog is the best solution in this case. Thank you for the hint [Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4188684/joachim-haglund)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/llProgressDialog"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text= "Laden ..."
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvProgressDialog"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to create a style and then use the style on creation

```
new ProgressDialog(Context, Resource.Style.progressDialogeStyle);
```

however if you for whatever reason do not want to do this, i dont think there is an easy way. you could set the view of the progressdialogue but then you would have to create the whole view manually.

Perhaps you could use .FindViewById to get the background view and change its backgroundcolor. feels like badpractise to use something other than a style though, may i ask why you do not want to do this?

Comment: I do not want to use a style, because these colors are user settings which can be changed on the run.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. I would suggest making your own custom progressdialog then, that way you can modify any part of it on the fly. Just make a custom view for an alertdialog which contains a progressbar. if you want more variations than the default progressbars, arbnb have made a very simple animation plugin called lottie.

Comment: yes, i think i will go with a full custom view alert dialog. Thanks for the answers